# RegEx in HTML split with preg-match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a corrupt html-page which i unfortunately can't parse with xml/xcode so i came up with regex. I'm a regexbeginner but I cant get the right result.

Source

```
<td>FIELD:</td> <td>VALUE<td>
```

I want to get the value and this is where I'm stuck

```
$regex = '{<td[^>]*<td>(.*?)</td>}';
```

edit: as a result I want an array where I can reach the value, so I'm just interested in the value

I'm thankfull for every hint.

cheers endo

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ... But anyway, what exactly do you expect that regex to do?

Comment: Just a thought, but why not correct the 'corrupt' page? Then JavaScript, and user-agents, will work better, and more consistently. Treat the disease, not the symptoms.

Comment: Just a note, you need some delimiters on that regex `'/{.....}/'`

Comment: @the_red_baron - `{...}` works as delimiters in PHP. You can also use `~...~`, `/.../`, and I think there are some other styles.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - and so I learn something new! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some immediately visible problems with your regex; for example, `<td[^>]*<td>` doesn't do what you think it does. But rather than suggest a different regex, let me urge you to do the sanest thing:

### Don't use regex for this!

Trust me. Don't do it. Others will come in here and suggest new regex patterns, and their patterns will all be **wrong**. [Regex isn't even up to the task of parsing clean HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649), so trying to use it on arbitrarily corrupted code is a recipe for madness. Try [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), which is made for this sort of thing. Depending on what's wrong with the HTML, a parser like [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) might also be able to work with it.

It may seem like a little more effort, but you'll *save* yourself time in the long run.

Comment: convinced to not use regex ^^

Comment: Don't be convinced to not-use regex; but be prepared for it to fail, and go spectacularly wrong, if you're using it in the wrong place, or for the wrong reasons. For this use-case, seriously: *don't*, for others, matching and/or replacing pieces of a string with a different piece of a string, or whatever, regex is *awesomely* powerful.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I agree with you, actually. I'm a big fan of regex and consider it extremely useful, even for certain tasks involving HTML. However, it's *definitely* not suited for what the asker is trying to do. My answer isn't "never use regex and HTML together," it's "avoid using regex to parse HTML, let alone HTML that isn't even well-formed."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`'{<td>.*?</td>\s+<td>(.*?)</td>}'`

But you missed a `/` in the html text
If, by corrupted, you mean missing slashes at closing tags, you can use this:

`'{<td>.*?</?td>\s+<td>(.*?)</?td>}'`
where the slashes in closing tags are now optional